# java - Can't get "append mode" on Filewriter to work for me

Tags: java

I've been all over the search and it seems like the given answers just don't work for me.

My code is relatively simple, it generates an array of Objects, populates it with some random strings and then tries to output to a file.  The idea is basically to generate a CSV file with some names, login names, passwords, etc.  and the names are strings of random letters (long story, it's for mass-populating an environment with users...)

I have a "Writer" class like this:

```
    public class Writer {
    public static void log(String message) throws IOException { 

     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("testlog.txt"), true); 
     out.println(message);

  out.close();
}
}
```

And a loop like this:

```
    for (int y=0; y < num_names; y++) {
           try {
            Writer.log(arrayTest[y].first + "," + arrayTest[y].last + "," +     arrayTest[y].loginName + "," + arrayTest[y].password +
                    "," + arrayTest[y].email);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Csvgenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


   System.out.println(arrayTest[y].first + "," + arrayTest[y].last + "," + arrayTest[y].loginName + "," + arrayTest[y].password + 
           "," + arrayTest[y].email);    

 }
```

My expectation is that I will loop through and for each object in arrayTest[] I output a single line of data to the file.
I included the System.out.println just for debugging.

When I run my code, the System.out.println proves that it works properly -- I get a list of 10 rows.  (num_names = 10 here)  so this proves that each time I get to this line of code, I have a unique "row" of data which gets printed out.

However, at the end of the run, the file "testlog.txt" only contains a single line -- the very last row in my output.

I've tried "out.append" instead of "out.println" but no difference.  It appears as though every time I call the logger it's creating the file anew for some reason.

So in other words if my console output (from the system.out.println) looks like this:

```
nxoayISPaX,aNQWbAjvWE,nanqwbajvwe,P@ssw0rd!,nanqwbajvwe@mylab.com
RpZDZAovgv,QOfyNRtIAN,rqofynrtian,P@ssw0rd!,rqofynrtian@mylab.com
SajEwHhfZz,VziPeyXmAc,svzipeyxmac,P@ssw0rd!,svzipeyxmac@mylab.com
sifahXTtBx,MRmewORtGZ,smrmewortgz,P@ssw0rd!,smrmewortgz@mylab.com
PlepqHzAxE,MQUJsHgEgy,pmqujshgegy,P@ssw0rd!,pmqujshgegy@mylab.com
VKYjYGLCfV,nuRKBJUuxW,vnurkbjuuxw,P@ssw0rd!,vnurkbjuuxw@mylab.com
YgvgeWmomA,ysKLVSZvaI,yysklvszvai,P@ssw0rd!,yysklvszvai@mylab.com
feglvfOBUX,UTIPxdEriq,futipxderiq,P@ssw0rd!,futipxderiq@mylab.com
RAQPPNajxR,vzdIwzFHJY,rvzdiwzfhjy,P@ssw0rd!,rvzdiwzfhjy@mylab.com
DeXgVFClyg,IEuUuvdWph,dieuuuvdwph,P@ssw0rd!,dieuuuvdwph@mylab.com
```

Then testlog.txt only contains a single line:

```
DeXgVFClyg,IEuUuvdWph,dieuuuvdwph,P@ssw0rd!,dieuuuvdwph@mylab.com
```

How do I force this to keep using the same file and just append new lines?

Answer (score 3):

On the constructor `PrintWriter(Writer out, boolean autoFlush)`, the second boolean argument is actually for autoflush, not append mode.

I think you intended to use `FileWriter(File file, boolean append)` constructor instead, ie:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("testlog.txt", true));
```

instead of

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("testlog.txt"), true);
```